# PHP version must be equal or higher than 5.6

Tags: php, ubuntu, cakephp

I have updated PHP 5.5.9 to PHP 5.6.31 using the command lines in Ubuntu. 
[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf5rR.png)

And then I was trying to install CakePHP, but it is showing that "your PHP version must be equal or higher than 5.6.0 to use CakePHP."

[This is the error message of cakePHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf2Op.png)

I am doing work in Linux(Ubuntu) Operating system.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP CLI version and the version configured with your web server can very well be different.  If you check `phpinfo()`, you can see exactly what paths and what not are in use.

Comment: Who downvoted this and why? You can have many versions of PHP installed and not all might be correctly configured for all environments.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. PHP CLI and PHP Apache are the different module. We have to notice the Apache server PHP version which is showing by-

```
<?php
phpinfo()
?>
```

To run the same version, first I disabled the PHP 5.5.9 version-

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

Then I enabled the PHP 5.6 version-

```
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

Restart the server-

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```